# MouseDragged is not working

Tags: java

can someone help me with this please, I have been following a book on learning to program in Java, copied one of their programs and thou it works the mouseDragged is not working. Cannot click on the ‘Hello Java!’ text and drag it round the screen. I have included the program but I just can’t see where I have gone wrong or what I have misted out.
I have seen the post: "MouseDragged & MouseMoved not working in Java Applet", but those methods are all in my program.

```
//file: HelloJava3.java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class HelloJava3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloJava3");
    frame.add( new HelloComponent3("Hello, Java!"));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}

class HelloComponent3 extends JComponent
implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    String theMessage;
    int messageX = 125, messageY = 95; //Coordinates of the message

    JButton theButton;

    int colorIndex; //Current index into someColors
    static Color[] someColors = {
            Color.black, Color.red,               Color.green,  Color.blue,  Color.magenta
    };

public HelloComponent3(String message) {
    theMessage = message;
    theButton = new JButton("Change Color");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(theButton);
    theButton.addActionListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString(theMessage, messageX, messageY);
}

public void mouseDgragged(MouseEvent e) {
    messageX = e.getX();
    messageY = e.getY();
    repaint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Did somebody push out button?
    if (e.getSource() == theButton)
        changeColor();
}

synchronized private void changeColor() {
    //Change the index to the next colour, awkwardly.
    if (++colorIndex == someColors.length)
        colorIndex = 0;
    setForeground(currentColor()); // Use the new colour.
    repaint();
}

synchronized private Color currentColor() {
    return someColors[colorIndex];
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Rather than copy the code, study the concepts as this will get you further. Also before posting questions, search for and study related tutorials as there are often many to be found (including on how to use mouse listeners and mouse motion listeners with Swing).

Comment: By copping the code and all the mistakes you make along the way you can  learn a lot from resolving them. Tutorials are great but being able to debug is greater and yes I did search for answer before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouseDragged method is being overridden and is doing nothing.  You should remove this or define it. I would remove the one that is overridden and add the @Override annotation to the other mouseDragged method assuming it is required by the interface you are extending.

remove this:

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Should probably appear like this in the code:

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  messageX = e.getX();
  messageY = e.getY();
  repaint();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have learned a lot from your explanations and your peace of code. It now works.

Comment: Glad to help, please accept this as the correct answer by clicking the check mark next to the solution.  Learning to code is rewarding, keep up the good work.